# How to JOIN without relational table in Symfony Doctrine with QueryBuilder between 2 entities

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an Entity Video related with a Entity Category and I need to run this SQL with Doctrine QueryBuilder, with this I can get the most used categories in all videos (1000+):

```
    SELECT c.*
    FROM Video v
    INNER JOIN video_category vc ON vc.video_id = v.id
    INNER JOIN Category c ON vc.category_id = c.id
    GROUP BY c.id
    HAVING COUNT(v.id) > 1000
    ORDER BY c.name ASC;
```

My querybuilder:

```
    $queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('c')
        ->from('AcmeVideoBundle:Video', 'v')
        // Can Doctrine join itself silently with relational info in the Entities?
        ->join('AcmeCategoryBundle:Category', 'c', Expr\Join::WITH, 'v.id = c.id')
        ->groupBy('c.id')
        ->having('COUNT(v.id) > 1000')
        ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery();
```

But the SQL query output by queryBuilder is this:

```
    SELECT c0_.id AS id0, c0_.NAME AS name1 
    FROM Video v1_ 
    INNER JOIN Category c0_ ON (v1_.id = c0_.id) 
    GROUP BY c0_.id 
    HAVING COUNT(v1_.id) > 1000
    ORDER BY c0_.NAME ASC
```

Without the relational table (video_category)

The Entities mapping:

```
    /**
     * Video
     *
     * @ORM\Table
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\VideoBundle\Entity\VideoRepository")
     */
    class Video
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\CategoryBundle\Entity\Category", cascade={"persist"})
         */
        private $category;

        // More fields, getters and setters etc...
    }

    /**
     * Category
     *
     * @ORM\Table
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\CategoryBundle\Entity\CategoryRepository")
     */
    class Category
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $name;

        // More fields, getters and setters etc...
    }
```

How can I use the relation table to run the original SQL query with doctrine Querybuilder? I missed something?

INFO: When I findBy{field}, persist, flush, clear on all entities works fine, the Doctrine relations are ok, I have a Video, Category and video_category tables fine, the original SQL query works perfect.

Comment: Did you try declaring the relation table like you did with your `JOIN`?

Comment: Yep: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 54 near 'video_category': Error: Class 'video_category' is not defined.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, solved, the problem was that the Entities isn't fully mapped for ManyToMany bidirectional relationship.

The Entities are now:

```
    class Video
    {
        /**
         * @var ArrayCollection
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\CategoryBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="video") // Note the inversedBy key
         */
        private $category;
    }

    class Category
    {
        /**
         * @var Video
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\VideoBundle\Entity\Video", mappedBy="category") // Again the inversed
         */
        private $video; // New field for bidirectional ManyToMany
    }
```

And the final QueryBuilder working (now with full alias version :P):

```
    $queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('category')
        ->from('AcmeCategoryBundle:Category', 'category')
        ->join('category.video', 'video')
        ->groupBy('category.id')
        ->having('COUNT(video.id) > 1000')
        ->orderBy('category.name', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery();
```

Best regards

Answer (score 15):

```
   // Can Doctrine join itself silently with relational info in the Entities?
    ->join('AcmeCategoryBundle:Category', 'c', Expr\Join::WITH, 'v.id = c.id')
```

Yes!  In fact that is one of the major reasons for using an ORM such as Doctrine 2.

Try:

```
->leftJoin('v.category','c')
```

The manual goes into more details though oddly enough is does not seem to have a join example.  Hence the common confusion.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

And you may not be aware of this but the United Nations has passed a resolution outlawing the use of abbreviations for aliases.  Just to be safe, try:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->addSelect('category')
    ->from('AcmeVideoBundle:Video', 'video')
    ->leftJoin('video.category', 'category')
    ->groupBy('category.id')
    ->having('COUNT(video.id) > 1000')
    ->orderBy('category.name', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery();
```

Comment: I love it the full name for alias, I put the short version for clarify the example in StackOverflow, is good known the people with the same point of view! In last hours I got this same Exception with other combination of ->select() and ->join() / innerJoin(): [Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near 'SELECT category': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias. I used your answered code :/